# populating multiple fields with same label via DocuSign API

Tags: docusignapi

We have several templates that take advantage of using same named labels to populate the data entered in one field to others with the same label throughout  envelope documents.

According to API method [Envelopes::EnvelopeRecipientTabs](https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/reference/Envelopes/EnvelopeRecipientTabs/), in order to make this work via the API, I needed to add `\\*` (two back slashes) prior to the label name so that data pushed to a field would populate all and not just the first occurrence of a field with that label.

example:  `"tabLabel": "\\*Contract_Number"`

This seemed to do the trick.

However, now I'm finding this works like a wild card. I have another field labeled "existing_contract_number" and the data for `\\*contract_number` populates this field.

I know I can change the name of the field so that the ending doesn't match, but there are many fields and many templates I will need to sift through to see if this is an issue elsewhere AND to fix this particular occurrence.

Is there something I am missing?  Can I get the data to populate in all fields that exactly match the tabLabel without using essentially a wildcard?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest listing the template's tabs or the envelope's tabs using a method such as [EnvelopeRecipientTabs::list](https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/reference/Envelopes/EnvelopeRecipientTabs/list) -- Note its `include_anchor_tab_locations` query parameter if you're using anchor tabs.

Once you have the entire list of tabs, update the values of just the desired tabs.

This may be more work than changing the template but will probably be a more generalized solution for your app.